# Android GridView's method setAdapter how to work?

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am try to figure out the Android Adapter how to associate with AdapterView.But I didn't understand the following code:

```
@Override
public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    if (mAdapter != null && mDataSetObserver != null) {
        mAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
    }

    resetList();
    mRecycler.clear();        
    mAdapter = adapter;

    mOldSelectedPosition = INVALID_POSITION;
    mOldSelectedRowId = INVALID_ROW_ID;

    // AbsListView#setAdapter will update choice mode states.
    super.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (mAdapter != null) {
        mOldItemCount = mItemCount;
        mItemCount = mAdapter.getCount();
        mDataChanged = true;
        checkFocus();

        mDataSetObserver = new AdapterDataSetObserver();
        mAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);

        mRecycler.setViewTypeCount(mAdapter.getViewTypeCount());

        int position;
        if (mStackFromBottom) {
            position = lookForSelectablePosition(mItemCount - 1, false);
        } else {
            position = lookForSelectablePosition(0, true);
        }
        setSelectedPositionInt(position);
        setNextSelectedPositionInt(position);
        checkSelectionChanged();
    } else {
        checkFocus();            
        // Nothing selected
        checkSelectionChanged();
    }

    requestLayout();
}
```

I didn't know where the variable mAdapter come from and I didn't understand why the code in this method can't to click to associate with associated method in Eclipse,Are they implementation in
native method ?

Comment: `mAdapter` is a member of the class this method is in, or a protected member a class that is inherited.

Comment: Android's setAdapter() method is same as the one you do for a listview . The mAdapter here must have been defined elsewhere in your code. Although from the code posted its difficult to understand what you want to achieve. Are you trying to implement a simple gridView?

Comment: The posted code above was android.widget.GridView#setAdapter method,you can find it in Android source code.

Answer (score 0):

mAdapter is inherite from parent class: android.widget.AbsListView.
They are not native code, I think it is Eclipse issue for not able to click to go to corresponding methods.